# jQuery autocomplete field not autocompleting when getting data from remote database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to get a jQuery autocomplete field to work with data from a remote DB, and I'm having no luck. Here's what I've attempted so far:

1.I have all of the necessary links to the source code in my header.

2.I have the following jQuery script written:

```
<script>
 $(function() {
   function log( message ) {

      $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $( "#projNo0" ).autocomplete({ //projNo0 is the name of the autocomplete field
      source: "projects.php",
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( ui.item ?
         "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
         "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

3.This is the PHP backend that's supposed to populate the autocomplete field projNo0 (the DB connection is handled elsewhere in the same file):

```
$return_arr = array();
if ($con2) //If the DB connection is successful
{
    //Get the user's input from projNo0
    $ac_term = "%".$_GET['term']."%";
    $query = $con2->prepare("SELECT CodeID FROM CodeTable WHERE 
        CodeID LIKE :term");
    $data = array('term'=>$ac_term);
    $query->execute($data);

    while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
    {
      $row_array['CodeID'] = $row['CodeID'];
      array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
      //echo $row['CodeID']; //line used for testing
      //echo '<br />'; //line used for testing
    } 
}
```

4.And here is the HTML for my autocomplete field. It's part of an array:

```
<p class="ui-widget">
<input type="text" name="projNo[]" id="projNo0" value="<? php echo $projNo[0]; ?>" />
</p>
```

I can confirm that there's no problem connecting to the remote DB. I'm able to echo out the array of values the SELECT statement returns. The jQuery script only works, however, when I hardcode an array of values into it. (Replace source "projects.php" with ["Bob","Carol","Ted","Alice"], for example.) When I right-click on the field and inspect it, the network activity shows that projects.php is being called and that it's accepting my input, appending it as a GET variable. The status of that activity is "OK". But I get no drop-down list of autofill suggestions.

Where is the break between my application and the database? I'm assuming that's where the problem is, since the script works with hardcoded values.

Comment: What does your script return? Pure json? Did you include the jquery-ui css files?

Comment: Yes, the ui css files are there. the jQuery script works fine when I use a hardcoded array of values within it, but not when I try to get the values from my database.

Comment: And you checked that your script is returning something? Show some example output of your script. Did you checked client-side what you are receiving?

Comment: When I run this from within projects.php: `echo json_encode(array_values($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0)));` using my own name as :term, I get ["Michael Benton"]. My name is in the database, so it's finding it okay. It's just not giving it to the JQuery script.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
  $row_array['CodeID'] = $row['CodeID'];
  array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
  //echo $row['CodeID']; //line used for testing
  //echo '<br />'; //line used for testing
}
```

With this

```
echo json_encode(array_values($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0)));
```

The point is - autocomplete expexts JSON-encoded string as an answer, and you return nothing from your script. Using `array_reduce` to get the resulting array is just my preference.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error when I copy/paste that. Is there a closing } or ) missing? Having trouble tracking it down.

Comment: Which php version are you using?

Comment: Semicolon at the end perhaps. And i'm an idiot, usually i use this when i need to pass value and label pairs to autocomplete.

Comment: We're on 5.3, so no problems there. Syntax error has been corrected, but the code you suggested didn't change anything, alas.

Comment: Another try. Also, can you watch a response on your projects.php and tell what's in there?

Comment: No joy with that one, either. I can only say that, when I watch the network activity in Inspect Element, projects.php is being called and that it's showing my input as being appended as a GET as I type it. So it looks like my input is hitting the PHP file, but it's not getting back to my jQuery function, for some reason.

Comment: I understand that, but what is the response of your script? You can see it too in Inspect Element.

Comment: I apologize if I seem thick here. I'm not sure if the PHP script is returning anything. When I type into the field, I see it being appended to projects.php and the status is OK and it shows the jQuery file referenced in my header link. this is in Google Chrome.

Comment: Can you manually call this script, with some valid `term` value and tell what the results are?

Comment: Absolutely. When I use my own name, I get this returned: `Michael Benton
[{"Username":"Michael Benton"}]`

Comment: your result should only contain ["Michael Benton"]. Remove all other echoes and make sure you have only values, without keys in the json_encoded array that you echo.

Comment: Okay, when I run this: `echo json_encode(array_values($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0)));` against my own name, I get `["Michael Benton"]`.